# cannot install devtools in r shiny docker

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I'm trying to build a docker image for my shiny app.  Below is my `dockerfile`. When I build my images, everything else seems fine, except I got error message `Error in library(devtools) : there is no package called ‘devtools’ Execution halted`.  I also tried `devtools::install_github('nik01010/dashboardthemes')` with no success.  I have non clue why?  What could go wrong? Do anyone know what is wrong with my dockerfile?  Thanks a lot.

```
# Install R version 3.6
FROM r-base:3.6.0

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev

# Download and install ShinyServer (latest version)
RUN wget --no-verbose https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/VERSION -O "version.txt" && \
    VERSION=$(cat version.txt)  && \
    wget --no-verbose "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-$VERSION-amd64.deb" -O ss-latest.deb && \
    gdebi -n ss-latest.deb && \
    rm -f version.txt ss-latest.deb

# Install R packages that are required
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('devtools', 'shiny','shinythemes','shinydashboard','shinyWidgets','shinyjs', 'tidyverse', 'dplyr', 'ggplot2','rlang','DT','lubridate', 'plotly',  'leaflet', 'mapview', 'tigris', 'rgdal', 'visNetwork', 'wordcloud2', 'arules'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "library(devtools)"
RUN R -e "install_github('nik01010/dashboardthemes')"


# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app /srv/shiny-server/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Copy further configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few approaches you might try.

**Easiest:**

Use `remotes::install_github` instead of `devtools`. `remotes` has many fewer dependencies if you don't need the other functionality.

**Second Easiest:**

Use [rocker/tidyverse](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/tidyverse/) image from Docker Hub instead of baseR image.

```
docker pull rocker/tidyverse
```

Change line 2:

```
FROM rocker/verse
```

**Hardest:**

Otherwise, you will need to figure out which dependencies you need to install inside your docker image before you can install `devtools`. It will likely be obvious if you try to install it interactively.

1. Make sure the container is running
2. Get the container name using `docker ps`
3. Start a shell with `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash`
4. Start `R` and try to install `devtools` interactively